# Can I connect my camera to my computer via USB and take pictures/video directly to my hard drive?

Tags: storage, camera

Currenly, I can take pictures and video with my Canon Powershot, and then upload them to my computer's hard drive.  I'd like to bypass my memory card altogether, and store media *directly* to my iMac.

Is there any way to do that? Would I need special camera software, or special OS X software?  Are there any ways to do something *similar,* if not exactly this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're attempting to do is called *tethering*.  It is possible with most digital SLR cameras, but I'm not aware of any point-and-shoot cameras (such as the Powershot) which support tethering.

Answer (score 2):

You could get an EyeFi memory card which will automatically save photos to your computer as you take them via your wireless home network. (If you take photos away from home, when you return, it will transfer the photos then, automatically.)

http://www.eye.fi/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is only possible with Canon's EOS SLR cameras along with the EOS utility found [here](http://tinyurl.com/n224l9). It cannot be done with powershot models.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DV camera, it is possible to capture directly to hard drive.

Normal capturing occurs in real-time, with the computer recording what the DV tape plays back.  Simply setting your capture software to record while the camera is running should let you capture directly onto the hard drive.

I've done this in previous versions of Adobe Premiere (v6 if I remember correctly); as always, you may get different results on different hardware/capture combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 eyeFi cards and this is definitely the way to go.

It has the high benefit to work with most of camera with SD cards; some recent models even integrate the possibility to disable/enable the wifi connection of the card. You can check which cameras are supported [here](http://support.eye.fi/cameras)

What you need is:

- EyeFi card X2 (Connect X2 or Pro X2 but not a "mobi"!!)=> e.g. in [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=eyefi)
- a WiFi network (on which the computer and card will be both connected)
- Their software that you can download from their site
- Configure the card with this software so it connects on the WiFi network and uploads  directly to the folder you have set up (pretty easy I have to admit: the interface is helping a lot)

Then you just take a picture/video, wait a bit and it's in your computer.

Not as fancy as tethering but at least it is working with small compact cameras.

Note: you can configure your EyeFi card to work on several WiFi networks.